# Change background color of DT table based on an external dataframe

Tags: r, dt

I'm displaying a table in DT where I want to show the p-values of a correlation matrix but have the background color reflect the R values.  I am finding resources and sample code on how to change the color of one column based on the value of another column that is also in the same table. My question is: How do I change the color of all columns based on an external table that is not being shown?  I can do this in reachable, but in this case I want to stick to using DT

Answer (score 2):

You could create a colors matrix, `cbind` it to the correlation matrix, and hide the colors columns:

```r
library(DT)

set.seed(123)

m <- matrix(rnorm(25,1),ncol=5)
mcor <- cor(m)
mcor.colors <- mcor > 0.5
mcor.formatted <- cbind(mcor,mcor.colors)

cols.keep <- paste0('V',1:5) 
cols.color <- paste0('V',6:10)


datatable(mcor.formatted,options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(targets = cols.color, visible = FALSE))
)) %>%
  formatStyle(cols.keep,
              cols.color,
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0,1), c('white','yellow'))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: @Raha, does this go in the expected direction? If not, thanks for clarification.

Comment: it does the job thanks